# Resolving the actual email address in SMTP

Tags: java, sockets, smtp

I have a socket setup in Java and the user could input their user ID and password to log into the mail's SMTP server. When sending out the email, I need to know the user's email address on the server so that I can put it into the `From:` header of the email. But sometimes, the user's ID may not be exactly the same as the address of his email. For eg, the user ID could be `abc_john` and the host name could be `smtp.smith.com` but the actual email address could be `john@mail.smith.com`. Something like that. That's the user name does not imply its actual email address.

Is there a way to resolve for its actual email address in Java? I am connecting tot he SMTP server using Socket, *not* the JavaMail API. I am hoping if there could be a SMTP command that could return the actual email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the SMTP server a `VRFY` command specifying the username as a parameter. If the server supports `VRFY` (it is an optional but recommended command), the response should include the full email address of the user's mailbox. Refer to [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/txt/rfc2821.txt) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot derive anything based on the username and SMTP server used. A single SMTP server can serve as the MX for a multitude of domains (for example my company use gmail as its mail provider, but our emailaddress are simply from our company-domain). And in the past (before the rise of spam), you could use - at least in theory - any SMTP server to send mail for any given e-mailaddress.

Simply put: the user will need to provide the full e-mailaddress, one way or another.

Comment: If the user can put in any address he wants to as his email address, wouldn't that facilitate spam and imposition? Like he could attempt to impose as some one else. Of course, the headers of the mail will reveal his identity but no everyone wouldn't read the headers all the time.

Comment: That depends on the exact configuration of the mailserver. Mailservers will normally disallow any e-mailaddress as sender which is not theirs, except when configured to allow this for specific users.